# Simulate execution of system back button

Tags: flutter, dart

There is a single screen in an app with a button in the center. When such button is pressed the following code will execute:

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

A black screen will be the next presentation after the given code finishes its execution. However, this is not the desired view. Instead, it's expected that the system pops out the app itself.

how can such a goal be accomplished?

Comment: Use `SystemNavigator.pop()`